# How Do I Sort a list of students?

Tags: c#

How do I sort a List by Name or by Age by not creating another cs file?
This method doesn't seem to work at all.

```
case 6:
{         //Sorting                 
    do
    {                       
        Console.WriteLine("1. Sort by Name");
        Console.WriteLine("2. Sort by Age");
        int choice = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        switch(choice)
        {                           
            case 1://Sort by Name

               st.Sort((a,b) => a.getName().CompareTo(b.getName()));
               ok = 1;
               break;

            case 2://Sort by Age

               st.Sort((a,b) => a.getAge().CompareTo(b.getAge()));
               ok = 1;
               break;                           
            default:Console.WriteLine("Not in the choices!"); ok = 0;
               break;                           
         }                      
    }
    while (ok != 1);
}
break;//case6-Sort
```

Comment: What means "This method doesn't seem to work at all."? Does it return values and if so how are they different from what you expect?

Comment: Define "doesn't work". What is the input? How are you testing the output? What do you see? What did you expect to see?

Comment: I was expecting to see my List sorted out by what choice the user picks. I have another case that views my list. But even though I sorted them, when I view my list it doesnt change at all and is still not sorted out by name/age.

Comment: You may consider some example-data and a short but full code-excample to reproduce this issue because by what you´ve posted by now should work as expected.

Answer (score 6):

Using LINQ should be easier:

```
var sorted = list.OrderBy(person => person.getName())
                 .ToList();
```

If you want to sort by one property use just `OrderBy`, if you want to further sort the list in case there are a few items with the same value, use `ThenBy`:

```
var sorted = list.OrderBy(person => person.getName())
                 .ThenBy(person => person.getAge())
                 .ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `Linq`

Order By Name

```
var students = st.OrderBy(s => s.Name).ToList();
```

Order By Age

```
var students = st.OrderBy(s => s.Age).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use LINQ:

```
// sort by name
var newList = st.OrderBy(a => a.getName()).ToList();

// sort by age
var newList = st.OrderBy(a => a.getAge()).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

Please do NOT use Linq if you specifically want to do an in-place sort of a List. It's an inappropriate solution (and it seems that people are suggesting it just because "it's newer").

Anyway, on to your question. Your code *should* work. Here's a compilable Console application which demonstrates it working.

Review this code and compare it to what you're doing. I suspect your problem lies without the area of code that you have shown us.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Demo
{
    class Person
    {
        private readonly string name;
        private readonly int    age;

        public Person(string name, int age)
        {
            this.name = name;
            this.age = age;
        }

        public string getName()
        {
            return name;
        }

        public int getAge()
        {
            return age;
        }
    }

    internal class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var persons = new List<Person>
            {
                new Person("C", 4),
                new Person("D", 1),
                new Person("A", 3),
                new Person("B", 2)
            };

            persons.Sort((a,b) => a.getName().CompareTo(b.getName()));
            print(persons); // Ordered by name "A", "B", "C", "D".

            persons.Sort((a, b) => a.getAge().CompareTo(b.getAge()));
            print(persons);  // Ordered by age "1", "2", "3", "4".
        }

        private static void print(List<Person> persons)
        {
            foreach (var person in persons)
                Console.WriteLine("Name: {0}, Age: {1}", person.getName(), person.getAge());

            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Linq is the most recent programming practice, you should use it in you case:

```
case 6:{//Sorting

                do{

                    Console.WriteLine("1. Sort by Name");
                    Console.WriteLine("2. Sort by Age");
                    int choice = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

                    switch(choice){

                        case 1://Sort by Name

                            students = st.OrderBy(s=>s.name);
                            ok = 1;
                            break;

                        case 2://Sort by Age

                            students = st.OrderBy(s=>s.age);
                            ok = 1;
                            break;

                        default:Console.WriteLine("Not in the choices!"); ok = 0;break;

                    }

                }while(ok != 1);}break;//case6-Sort
```

Comment: st.OrderBy doesn't sort initial  collection. it returns a new one

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try

SortedList

Hope that will help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
//Sort by Name
emp = emp.OrderBy(x => x.Name).ToList();

//Sort by Age
emp = emp.OrderBy(x => x.Age).ToList();
```